# c# php client long polling

Tags: c#, php

**I've find almost two day and cannot find any tutorial about c# client long polling. Can anyone give me a example or help me solve this problem. So,This is my php file.**

b.php

```
 <?  
 set_time_limit(0);   
    $file = 'test.txt';   
    $js_time = !empty($_GET['time']) ? intval($_GET['time']) : 0;  
    $file_time = filemtime($file);
    while($file_time <= $js_time){   
    usleep(10000);  
    clearstatcache();  
    $file_time = filemtime($file);  
    }  
    $info = file_get_contents($file);  
    echo $info;  
    ?>
```

Second.php

```
function test(){  
    var aj;  
    try{aj=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}  
    catch(e){  
        try{aj=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}  
        catch(E){aj=false;}  
    }  
    var time = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);  
    if(!aj&&typeof XMLHttpRequest!=undefined)aj=new XMLHttpRequest();  
    aj.open("GET","b.php?time="+time,true);  
    aj.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8');  
    aj.onreadystatechange=function(){  
        if(aj.readyState==4&&aj.status==200){  
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = aj.responseText;  
            test();  
            //alert('aa');
        }  
    }  
    aj.send(null);  
}  
test();  
</script>
```

c#

```
 string URL = "http://localhost/gcm_server_php/b.php?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString() ;
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        string responseBytes = webClient.DownloadString(URL);
        string responsefromserver = responseBytes;
            a.Content=responsefromserver;
        webClient.Dispose();
```

Using this c# code only can get one time . Anyone can help me use c# to long polling b.php?Thank for the help and sorry for my poor english. :(

Comment: If you are using c#, have you looked into signalr?

Comment: i edit my question and paste my c# code already,please review again! Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a good tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20

Comment: Thank for the reply but this tutorial is using the asp.net language. Any tutorial is wpf push to php or wpf long polling to the php?

Comment: Thank you! i found the example!